# can we implement Resilience4j @Retry on JPA repository methods like findAll, findbyId etc?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, resilience4j-retry, jparepository

@Repository
interface Test extends JpaRepository<EntityName,String> {

@Retry(name="database")
Optional findById(Id id);

}

can we implement @Retry on JpaRepository methods ?

if some issue occur with findById() method it will retry 2 times and circuit breaker will execute.